# jQuery not working in IE9 for hiding options

Tags: javascript, jquery

For this page: http://rmetro.uscav.com/az/fire/duty-shirts/09820.html

It hides options based on the URL. Any idea what may be the culprit besides IE9 just being terrible?

```
<script>
$j(window).load(function(){
    var url = window.location.href;
    url =  url.split('/');
var word = url['3'].replace(/-/g,' ');
   var select =  $j('#product-options-wrapper').find('div.option label:contains("Patch Type")').parents('div.option').find('select');
    var totalOption = select.find('option').length;
    var count = 0;
    select.find('option').each(function(i){
        if($j(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(word) == -1){
            $j(this).wrap('<span>').hide();
            count++;
        }

        if(count === totalOption){
            select.find('option').each(function(){
                if($j(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf('generic') >= 0){
                    if($j(this).parent().is('span')){
                        $j(this).unwrap().show();
                    }
                }
            });   
        }

        if(i+1 === totalOption){
            select.find('option').eq(1).unwrap().show();
        }
      });

      if(word.indexOf('ca') == -1){
        $j('#product-options-wrapper').find('div.option label:contains("San Diego Badge Type")').parents('div.option').hide();
      }
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Hiding options may not work on all browsers. And also, wrapping an option in a span leads to invalid markup! Use `url[3]` as array index is numeric.

Comment: Im not worried about having invalid markup. Site only needs to work for internal use only.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error on your page:

```
TypeError: $j(...).cycle is not a function
```

Maybe browsers differ in how they deal with it. I suggest you fix that first, and then have a nother go.